# Running a function that returns Try asynchronously

Tags: scala, error-handling, concurrency, future

Suppose I've got `foo: A => Try[B]` and want to run it asynchronously with `Future`, e.g.:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}

def foo(s: String): Try[Int] = Try(s.toInt)
def futureFoo(s: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = Future(foo(s).get)
```

Since I don't like using `get` method I am rewriting `futureFoo` like this:

```
def futureFoo(s: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] =
  Future(foo(s)).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
```

Does it make sense? Is there any helper function I missed that does exactly that?

Comment: It seems there is no helper function. Maybe make your own helper function `FutureHelper.deferTry` and hide the `.get` in there where no one ever has to look at it again. :-)

Comment: @Thilo I would probably use `flatMap(Future.fromTry)` instead of `get` in this helper function.

Answer (score 3):

Consider making the meaning of `get` more explicit by folding `Try` like so

```
Future(foo(s).fold(throw _, identity))
```

however it should be safe to call `get` inside `Future`, despite it being aesthetically jarring,

```
Future(foo(s).get)
```

because `Future` internally uses `Try` to handle throws anyway. For example,

```
def foo(s: String): Try[Int] = Try(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))
def futureFoo(s: String): Future[Int] = Future(foo(s).get)
futureFoo("foo") andThen { case e => println(e) }
```

outputs

```
Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: boom!)
```

Comment: Thanks, `get` is safe and straightforward but ugly, Maybe I just need to write a helper function `runAsFuture (A => Try[B]) => (A => Future[B])` to hide the ugliness.

Comment: How about `Future(foo(s).fold(throw _, identity))`?

Comment: Hmm.. If you really don't like `.get`, that `flatMap` looks the least clumsy to me.

Comment: @MarioGalic I'd prefer `flatMap` instead :)

Comment: Yes, definitely likewise.

Comment: Maybe a drawback of `get` is all the runtime overhead of throwing an exception.